# How does Atlassian Bamboo recognise python pytest reports

Tags: python, pytest, bamboo, pytest-html

I have some Integration tests written in Python3 using pytest. I am using pytest-html to generate an html report from it. How can I make Bamboo recognize/show this report.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you produce the html report in bamboo solely for the purpose of continuous integration, you could export the results of your tests to xml instead via:

```
pytest yourpath --junitxml=..\pytest.xml
```

and run the JUnit parser plugin from bamboo on `pytest.xml`.